# Consuming Azure table storage Tablelogger.cs

Tags: c#, botframework, azure-table-storage

Hi guys im following this [tutorial](https://chatbotslife.com/managing-state-and-logging-chat-history-in-microsoft-bot-framework-aeb330c688c5) on how to consume and log the conversation history using the [tablelogger.cs](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Azure/blob/master/CSharp/Library/Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Azure/TableLogger.cs#L60)

It uses this code on the global.asax to write the conversation history using the tablelogger implementation.

```
var tableName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TableName"].ToString();
    var account = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["StorageConnectionString"].ConnectionString);

    //Azure StateData
    Conversation.UpdateContainer(
        builder =>
        {
            //azure botdata
            builder.RegisterModule(new AzureModule(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()));
            var store = new TableBotDataStore(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["StorageConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
            builder.Register(c => store)
               .Keyed<IBotDataStore<BotData>>(AzureModule.Key_DataStore)
               .AsSelf()
               .SingleInstance();
            //azure conversation history
            account.CreateCloudTableClient().GetTableReference(tableName).DeleteIfExists();
            builder.RegisterModule(new TableLoggerModule(account, tableName));
        });
```

It works great, however i notice that it will drop the whole conversation table, when i try to run and debug my code on VS. Is this the one causing it to drop the table?

```
account.CreateCloudTableClient().GetTableReference(tableName).DeleteIfExists();
```

if yes then how can i prevent it to drop? can i simply remove the deleteifexist() method? im worrying that the table will be dropped while other users are still conversing with the bot.

Comment: Don't you want `CreateIfNotExists` as opposed to `DeleteIfExists`?

Comment: i honestly don't know, why such condition was inserted in the first place, i'm just simply following his tutorial since i'm new in this azure table thing,

Comment: Agreed, it is a bit bizarre. You could contact the author since it's probably a mistake on his part.

Comment: but upon closer inspection, there is a createifnotexists method already on the load method of the tablelogger.cs implementation.

Comment: I guess the author wanted a clean slate each time you start the application / configure the DI container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a look to the "official" sample on GitHub for Table Storage, you will see that the line you indicated is not necessary: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Azure/blob/master/CSharp/Samples/AzureTable/Global.asax.cs

To set DataStore:

```
var store = new TableBotDataStore(CloudStorageAccount.DevelopmentStorageAccount);
builder.Register(c => store)
    .Keyed<IBotDataStore<BotData>>(AzureModule.Key_DataStore)
    .AsSelf()
    .SingleInstance();
```

To set TableLogger:

```
builder.RegisterModule(new TableLoggerModule(account, tableName));
```

As told in the comments, it must be a special need of the person that made the tutorial you used, you should remove it.

Looks like the line about Deleting come from the tests: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Azure/blob/master/CSharp/Tests/Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Azure.Tests/LoggerTests.cs

Comment: hey man, thanks for answering again, Im actually okay with the table azure part( the one that saves the bot data), my concern is with the tablelogger.cs implementation, i want to save the conversation history between the bot and the user as well, so i followed his tutorial that logs the conversation history by adding these two lines to the global.asax part.

Comment: //azure conversation history
            
account.CreateCloudTableClient().GetTableReference(tableName).DeleteIfExists();
           

 builder.RegisterModule(new TableLoggerModule(account, tableName));

Comment: Sorry for the mix. You just need the last line to register you TableLogger. I edited the answer, will try to add a source to official info later

Comment: Looks like the error of adding this line may come from that Test where it is also used: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Azure/blob/master/CSharp/Tests/Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Azure.Tests/LoggerTests.cs

Comment: thanks man, should i do a deletion or clean up of the chat history as well? lets say after x amount of days?

Comment: It's up to you and your needs about this history!